# Photoshop Save Selection

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I work with PSDs that have the same layout frequently. I need to extract a few areas in each, and these areas are always the same. Same position, same size.

I know I can save a selection, but I was wondering if I can pull that selection into the next PSD I work with.

Answer (score 2):

Saved selections are merely alpha channels in Photoshop.

[image: saved selection]

You can copy channels between files by simply dragging the alpha channel from the **Channels Panel** of the old document to the window of the new document. This will create a new alpha channel in the new document. The selections will then appear in `Select > Load Selection...`. If your documents are the same dimensions, the alpha channels will be in the same position in both documents. Holding down the <kbd>Shift</kbd> when dragging ensures the dragged channel is placed in the same relative position as the old channel if the two documents are different dimensions.

Another method is to simply Right-Click/Control-Click the alpha channel and choose `Duplicate Channel...` from the contextual menu. When the duplicate options dialog pops up, select the document you want to duplicate the channel to and hit OK.

[image: duplicate channel]